# Drilldown using HighStocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am using HighStocks v5.0.7 for creating graphs. For a specific graph I would like to implement drilldown feature. 
Do I need to add any additional modules for this?
Currently I tried without any additional modules which is not working.

Note: I am working on Ruby on Rails App.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I enabled drill down by downloading the drilldown js file from http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js and updated application.js by adding `//= require highcharts/modules/drilldown`.

This is the same for highstock as well.